# Mali - French colonial rule

Tags: colonization, africa, french-empire

So I'm researching the time of the french colonial rule in Mali at the moment.

But there are some thing I don't understand, especially the part where the Mali region gets "added"(?) to french-sudan. Do you know of any map that shows all the different phases? Especially the phase where Mali was invaded by the french but not yet added to french-sudan. Can anyone explain how the whole region became the mali it is today?

Comment: This map summarizes the rapid colonial expansion that occurred during the ***Race for Africa*** in the last decades of the 19th Century: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a8/Scramble-for-Africa-1880-1913.png The French colonies of North-West Africa were initially administered as the separate colonies of Algeria, Morocco, Tunisia, French Equatorial Africa and French West Africa. Mali was part of the last, while modern Chad (presumably what you mean by French Sudan) was part of the French Equatorial Africa . What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Sudan

In the 1880s, the French began setting up military outposts in what was called Upper Senegal, which included Mali and parts of other countries. There was no civilian administration yet.

In 1890, Upper Senegal became French Sudan and gained a civilian administration. Then, French Sudan went through a series of territorial changes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkcNV.jpg

Then, in the 60s, French Sudan became Mali.